# WebserverConfiguration Symfony

Tags: php, apache, symfony, vagrant

in advance im new in development :-P

I am trying to setup a symfony project (http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/01?orm=Doctrine)

so i setup a working local enviroment with apache,msql and php and i did this with vagrant.

Now i have a problem to setup the web server configuration.

Vagrantfile is like this:

```
....
    Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
        config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
        config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"

        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4561
....
```

so i put this:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
    NameVirtualHost 10.10.0.5:4561

# This is the configuration for jobeet
    Listen 10.10.0.5:4561

    <VirtualHost 10.10.0.5:4561>
      ServerName jobeet.localhost
      DocumentRoot "/vagrant/web"
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      <Directory "/vagrant/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
      </Directory>

      Alias /sf "/vagrant/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf"
      <Directory "/vagrant/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

in vagrant etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

When i try to open "10.10.0.5:4561"i get a 500 error.

when i try to open "10.10.0.5" it ouput the index of everything (apps, cache, config, data, web, vagrantfile, ....)

someone knows what im doing wrong?

greetz

Comment: If you are using this to learn then I would recommend you stop learning using the legacy version of Symfony. As it says on the 1.x homepage "**As of November 2012, symfony 1.x is not maintained anymore and you are encouraged to have a look at Symfony2 for any new projects."**

Comment: ok, you are right :-) but anyway it would be nice for me to have a solution here for a better understanding :-)

Comment: Configuration is very well documented for the most popular web servers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: @JakubZalas your link is for **current/2.x** but OP is asking about **1.x**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i just deleted the .htaccess file and now its working.
I know that is not a good thing, but my project will never be in the internet.